# When to use an exception instead of a boolean

Tags: java

Let say you have a method that checks if the argument (Answer) is correct and check if the question already have answers in the list that is also correct:

```
public void addAnswer(Answer answer) {
    if (answer.isCorrect()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I only want one answer to be correct in the list. I have multiple options. I could throw an exception, I could ignore it, I could return some boolean value from the addAnswer that tells me if the operation was ok or not. How are you supposed to think in such scenarios?

Comment: I would suggest the boolean instead of exception throwing. As conditional check is always preferred exception throwing.

Comment: @manojchauhan If you have a reason for this assertion please provide it. Dogma is of no real interest.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is quite costly performance wise. I only do so when I offer an API to be used by others (or by other layers in my application). Within local code I avoid throwing exceptions. Usually there are good alternatives using return types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This entirely depends on what you **want** to achieve. Should the caller of your method already have made sure that it doesn't add two correct answers? Is it a sign of a **programming error** if that happens? Then throw an exception, but definitely **an unchecked exception**.

If your method's purpose is to relieve the caller from enforcing the one-true-answer invariant (I doubt that, though), then you can just arrange to signal via a `boolean` return value, which makes it only an optional information channel for the caller.

If there is **no way** to know in advance whether there are other correct answers—for example, the answers are added concurrently from several threads or even processes (via a database)—then it would be meaningful to throw a **checked exception**.

Bottom line: there is no one-size-fits-all best practice, but there is a best practice for every scenario you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 13):

The rule is pretty simple: *Use exceptions on exceptional, erroneous, unpredicted failures*. Don't use exceptions when you *expect* something to happen or when something happens really often.

In your case it's not an error or something truly rare that an answer is not correct. It's part of your business logic. You *can* throw an exception, but only as part of some validation (assertion) if you expect an answer at given point to always be correct and suddenly it's not (precondition failure).

And of course if some failure occurs while checking correctness (database connection lost, wrong array index) exception are desired.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how expected, predictable, or frequent an exception is: it is about whether it requires the unit of work to be aborted, or just to take an alternate path. In a public API this can never be known in advance and the best one can do is an educated guess. That's why a public API should never involve checked exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

The exception police will be down on you like a ton of bricks, and me for this answer, with statements like "don't use exceptions for flow control" and "don't use exceptions for normal conditions".

The trouble with the first statement is that exceptions *are* a form of flow control. This makes the argument self-contradictory, and therefore invalid.

The trouble with the second statement is that it seems to inevitably go along with endlessly redefining exceptional conditions  as normal. You will find examples in this very site: for example, a lively discussion where the police insisted that EOF was 'normal' and therefore that EOFException shouldn't be caught, despite the existence of dozens of Java APIs that don't give you any choice in the matter. Travel far enough down this path and you can end up with nothing that is exceptional whatsoever, and therefore no occasion to use them at all.

These are not logical arguments. These are unexamined dogmas.

The original and real point, back in about 1989 when it was first formulated, was that *you shouldn't throw exceptions to yourself, to be handled in the same method:* in other words, *don't treat it as a GOTO.* This principle continues to have validity.

The point about checked exceptions is that you *force* the caller to do something about handling them. If you believe, on your own analysis, that this is what you want, use an exception. Or, if you are using an API that forces you to catch them, catch them, at the appropriate level (whatever that is: left as an exercise for the reader).

In other words, like most things in the real world, it is up to your discretion and judgment. The feature is there to be used, or abused, like anything else.

@Exception police: you will find me in the telephone book. But be prepared for an argument.

Comment: +1 More of a rant than an answer, but I liked it :) The advice "don't use exceptions for flow control" is mainly copy-pasted from Effective Java. The whole item on exceptions there is quite misguided in my book, starting with "Checked exceptions are a wonderful feature of the Java programming language." It almost sounds like sarcasm.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've never read *Effective Java,* but I've been hearing that piece of advice for 30 years. Strange that you state this a rant. It is a very carefully reasoned piece of work actually.

Comment: The best rants _are_ carefully reasoned pieces of work :) What makes it a rant is the emotional wording like "The exception police will be down on you like a ton of bricks". BTW funny to lead this conversation at a rate of one message in nine years :D

Comment: It was a joke, actually, but in any case one so-called 'emotional' wording in eight closely reasoned paragraphs hardly makes it 'mostly a rant'. Sense of proportion is absent here. Interesting that I was still writing about telephone books in 2012. Haven't clapped eyes on one for years.

Answer (score 1):

An exception thrown from a method enforces the callers to take some action in the anticipation of the exception occurring for some inputs. A return value doesn't enforce the same and so it is up to the caller to capture it and take some action.

If you want the callers to handle the scenario to take some corrective action, then you should throw a checked exception (sub class of `java.lang.Exception`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your API is error prone. I'd use the following scheme instead:

```
public class Question {

    private List<Answer> answers;
    private int mCorrect;

    // you may want a List implementation without duplicates
    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers, int correct) {
        this.answers = answers;
        // check if int is between bounds
        mCorrect = correct;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect(Answer answer) {
        return answers.indexOf(answer) == mCorrect;
    }
}
```

because an `Answer` by itself is simply a statement, and usually cannot be `true` of `false` without being associated to a `Question`. This API makes it impossible to have zero or more than one correct answers, and forces the user to supply the correct one when he adds answers, so your program is always in a consistent state and simply can't fail.

Before deciding how to signal errors, it's always better to design the API so that errors are less common as possible. With your current implementation, you have to make checks on your side, and the client programmer must check on his side as well. With the suggested design no check is needed, and you'll have correct, concise and fluent code on both sides.

Regarding when to use a `boolean` and when to use `Exception`s, I often see boolean used to mirror the underlying API (mostly low level C-code).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tomasz Nurkiewicz's response. I cant comment on it because I'm a new user. I would also recommend that if the addAnswer() method is not always going to add the answer (because they already exists a correct one), name it to suggest this behaviour. "add" is suggest normal collections behaviour.

```
public boolean submitAnswer(Answer answer); // returns true is answer accepted
```

Your exact solution may depend on the bigger picture about your application that we dont know about.  Maybe you do want to throw an Exception but also make it the responsibility of the caller to check if adding the Answer is valid.

It's all a rich tapestry.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it in this way:

```
 public class Question { 

    private int questionId; 
    private final Set<Answer> options = new HashSet<Answer>();
    private final Set<Answer> correctAnswers = new HashSet<Answer>();

    public boolean addAnswer(Answer answer) throws WrongAnswerForThisQuestionException {
        if(!answer.isValid(questionId)) {
            throw new WrongAnswerForThisQuestionException(answer, this);
        }
        if (answer.isCorrect(questionId)) {
           correctAnswers.add(answer);
        }
        return options.add(answer);
    }
}
```